# Assert to check string contains only numeric values

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I want to write a JUNIT test case for checking that a String contains only numeric values.
Can anybody suggest me to do so. I am new to junit test case and i cud not find any way to write an assert for it.
Please suggest.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

If you use **AssertJ**, you have the method "containsOnlyDigits"

```
@Test
void shouldContainOnlyDigits() {
        assertThat("123").containsOnlyDigits();
}
```

or you can improve the check if you have a String that should contain a padded number:

```
@Test
void shouldContainOnlyDigits() {
        assertThat("001").hasSize(3).containsOnlyDigits();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Integer.parseInt(string)`. If string contains characters other than numbers then method will throw `NumberFormatException`.

```
try{
   Integer.parseInt(inputString)
}catch(NumberFormatException exception){
   //assert fail
}
```

Comment: befor it i want an assert for integer check